# Why do html rendared emails not recognize cdn based css?

Tags: python, django

I would like to send a HTML email formatted with Materialize CSS in Django, can any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML emailing does not support separate CSS. You have to define the style in the element.

Comment: just checked it out from google and found a post saying the same thing. Thank you for your answer.